# Laravel API routes not working with Postman

Tags: laravel, api

My route/api.php has these routes:

```
Route::post('/signup' , 'UserApiController@signup');
Route::post('/logout' , 'UserApiController@logout');
Route::post('/verify' , 'UserApiController@verify');
```

but when I'm trying to access from Postman like this, it shows object not found:

```
localhost/my_webiste/api/signup
```

here the userapicontroller signup function:

```
public function signup(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
            'social_unique_id' => ['required_if:login_by,facebook,google','unique:users'],
            'device_type' => 'required|in:android,ios',
            'device_token' => 'required',
            'device_id' => 'required',
            'login_by' => 'required|in:manual,facebook,google',
            'first_name' => 'required|max:255',
            'last_name' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'mobile' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required|min:6',
        ]);

    try{

        $User = $request->all();

        $User['payment_mode'] = 'CASH';
        $User['password'] = bcrypt($request->password);
        $User = User::create($User);

        return $User;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
         return response()->json(['error' => trans('api.something_went_wrong')], 500);
    }
}
```

here the postman output of post request of `localhost/mywebsite/api/signup` :

```
    <title>Object not found!</title>
    <link rev="made" href="mailto:postmaster@localhost" />
   <h1>Object not found!</h1>
   The requested URL was not found on this server.
   If you entered the URL manually please check your
spelling and try again.
```

Comment: show ur postman request

Comment: Are you running your api with `php artisan` or inside `apache`? Usually when you run `php artisan serve` it is hosted in default port of 8000. So you need to use port number in postman.

Comment: http://localhost/gudu/api/signup

Comment: i am directly making the post request in postman

Comment: @Nandan try the URL with the protocol `http://localhost/mywebsite/api/signup`

Comment: same output object not found i think my path is wrong

Answer (score 13):

Make sure, in your postman, to add the header `accept` = `application/json`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct. It seems like you are missing public from url

```
localhost/my_webiste/public/api/signup
```

Comment: i had also tried this but error 404 not found and here the middleware for api.php     protected function mapApiRoutes()
    {
        Route::group([
            'middleware' => 'api',
            'namespace' => $this->namespace,
            'prefix' => 'api/user',
        ], function ($router) {
            require base_path('routes/api.php');
        });
    }

Comment: You request with api/signup not api/user . Remove namespace and prefix then try you can access your Controller method or not . I think it's will be better for debugging what's is going wrong with your Route group by checking one by one.