# Laravel API Response - Redirects to login page

Tags: laravel

Here's my Authenticated middleware:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate as Middleware;

class Authenticate extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * Get the path the user should be redirected to when they are not authenticated.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return string|null
     */
    protected function redirectTo($request)
    {
        if ($request->expectsJson()){
            return response()->json(['message' => "Token is expired"], 401);
        }
        if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
            return route('login');
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my api.php

```
 Route::middleware(['auth:api'])->prefix('notifications')->namespace('Notification')->group(function () {
        Route::post('/send', 'NotificationController@send');
    });
```

I send a request with a postman with headers content-type JSON.
But It always redirects to the homepage. No answers as JSON.

What's wrong with that?

I'm already lost my mind.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel API routes not working with Postman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53424901/laravel-api-routes-not-working-with-postman)

Comment: `Content-Type` tells the server the type of content you are sending. `Accept` will tell the server what you are willing to accept as a response

Answer (score 27):

in your request header add

Accept  --- application/json[image]