# Not getting the json response in a post request using laravel

Tags: laravel

I have this controller:

```
class AuthController extends Controller
{
    public function login(Request $request)
        {
        if (!Auth::attempt($request->only('email', 'password'))) {
        return response()->json([
        'message' => 'Invalid login details'
                ], 401);
            }

        $user = User::where('email', $request['email'])->firstOrFail();

        $token = $user->createToken('auth_token')->plainTextToken;

        return response()->json([
                'access_token' => $token,
                'token_type' => 'Bearer',
        ]);
        }

    public function register(Request $request)
        {
        $validatedData = $request->validate([
                    'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
                    'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
                    'username' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
                    'password' => 'required|string|min:8',
        ]);

            $user = User::create([
                    'name' => $validatedData['name'],
                    'email' => $validatedData['email'],
                    'username' => $validatedData['username'],
                    'password' => Hash::make($validatedData['password']),
            ]);

        $token = $user->createToken('auth_token')->plainTextToken;

        return response()->json([
                    'access_token' => $token,
                    'token_type' => 'Bearer',
        ]);
        }

    public function me(Request $request)
    {
    return $request->user();
    }
}
```

And here is my api.php file for the routes:

```
Route::post('/me', [AuthController::class, 'me'])->middleware('auth:sanctum');
Route::post('/register', [AuthController::class, 'register']);
Route::post('/login', [AuthController::class, 'login']);
```

So if I do this post request with POstman:  http://127.0.0.1/api/register?name=luis ruiz flores&email=luis@gmail.com&username=llrr00&password=password
I should get a json with the access_token and the token_type, but what I get is the login view of my webpage.
Any idea why this happens?
Thak you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel API routes not working with Postman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53424901/laravel-api-routes-not-working-with-postman)

Comment: Why are you submitting POST content ir your URI instead of request body?

Answer (score 0):

You should define Headers in postman to be {"Accept": "application/json"}
to let laravel know this request will be JSON,[image] not a web response.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `Content-type` header to `application/json`. I believe Laravel doesn't allow a wildcard `Content-type` like `*/*` when it returns json. But I might be very wrong about it. I just had the same issue and thats how I managed to resolve it.

Also the url shouldn't be the way it is. You send your authentication info in url query params, but sensitive info, like passwords, should be sent with POST http method, and should be inside the request body. Notice the 'body' tab instead of 'Params' tab.

[Setting Content-type in Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1txC.png)

[Post request in Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GnqYS.png)

Answer (score 0):

Controller

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use App\Models\User;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

        if (!Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'Invalid login details'
            ], 401);
        }

        $user = $request->user();
        $token = $user->createToken('auth_token')->plainTextToken;

        return response()->json([
            'access_token' => $token,
            'token_type' => 'Bearer',
        ]);
    }

    public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $validatedData = $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'username' => 'required|string|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:8',
        ]);

        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $validatedData['name'],
            'email' => $validatedData['email'],
            'username' => $validatedData['username'],
            'password' => Hash::make($validatedData['password']),
        ]);

        $token = $user->createToken('auth_token')->plainTextToken;

        return response()->json([
            'access_token' => $token,
            'token_type' => 'Bearer',
        ]);
    }

    public function me(Request $request)
    {
        $user = $request->user();

        return response()->json($user);
    }
}
```

routes

```
use App\Http\Controllers\AuthController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::group(['prefix' => 'api'], function () {
    Route::post('/me', [AuthController::class, 'me'])->middleware('auth:sanctum');
    Route::post('/register', [AuthController::class, 'register']);
    Route::post('/login', [AuthController::class, 'login']);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**